# Cannot install anything on Vista Home Premium 32-bit with SP-2, Will I be able to upgrade to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-installer

I can not install important updates.  Anything I download will not install.

Error message is that

> Windows Installer Services cannot be accessed. This can occur if installer is not correctly installed.  Contact your support personnel for assistance

When trying to download important updates, install fails with error code `80070641`  & error code `641`.

I have System Mechanic installed and evidently has removed my installer according to others sites I have been searching. So with this problem I cannot even download another windows installer and I am going to upgrade to Windows 7.

My question is will I be able to install 7 without this installer?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove System Mechanic to start with.  Then see if you can install/reinstall [Windows Installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288).